# How to update this PHP validation case to support a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, validation, multidimensional-array

I am using a PHP validation script that only supports a single-dimensional array.

How can this switch case be modified so a multi-dimensional array will work?

Currently, it just shows a select field as being empty, when it actually has a selected value.

**Switch case:**

```
case 'in-array' :
    if (!(in_array($value, $rule->criteria))) {
        $this->_errors[$rule->fieldname] = $rule->message;
        return;
    }
    break;
```

**Call to require validation on State field:**

```
$validator->addRule('state', 'Please select a state', 'in-array', $states);

$validator->addEntries($_POST);
$validator->validate();

$entries = $validator->getEntries();

foreach ($entries as $key => $value) {
  ${$key} = $value;
}
```

**States array:**

```
$states = array('AL' => 'Alabama',
                'AK' => 'Alaska',
                'AZ' => 'Arizona',
                'AR' => 'Arkansas',
                'CA' => 'California',
                'CO' => 'Colorado',
                'CT' => 'Connecticut',
                'DE' => 'Delaware',
                'DC' => 'District Of Columbia',
                'FL' => 'Florida',
                'GA' => 'Georgia',
                'HI' => 'Hawaii',
                'ID' => 'Idaho');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `$value` is the array key, not the array value. Try adding [`array_key_exists`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) to your `case 'in-array'` if -

```
if (!(in_array($value, $rule->criteria)) && !(array_key_exists($value, $rule->criteria)))
```

Comment: Wow. That was easy. THANKS!!